# Link third party static library in cmake project

Tags: c, cmake, cmakelists-options

I have a cmake project with multiple subprojects. In one of those subprojects, I need to use an external static library (located in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext_lib`) and the `CMakeLists.txt` file looks something like this (approach 1):

```
project(my_project)
set(SRC my_project.c)
add_library(external_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(external_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext_lib/libext.a INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext_lib/include")
add_library(my_project SHARED ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(my_project PRIVATE external_lib)
```

This works fine and compiles nicely. However, the parts, which relates to the external lib, I would like to have in a separate `CMakeLists.txt` file. I thought I could just make a new `CMakeLists.txt` in the same folder as my external static lib is located (i.e. `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext_lib`) with the following contents (approach 2)

```
project(external_lib)
message("External lib CMakelists.txt entered")
add_library(external_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(external_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext_lib/libext.a INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext_lib/include")
```

And then add `add_subdirectory("ext_lib)` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` file and just use `target_link_libraries(my_project PRIVATE external_lib)` in the `my_project` sub-project. But that does not work. Can someone give me hint what I am missing?

(I only added `message(...)` to see if the `CMakeLists.txt` was included)

EDITED:

With not working I mean it does not compile correctly - I get `fatal error: ext_lib.h: No such file or directory #include "ext_lib.h"` (with approach 2)

I have looked at the generated `.cmake` files and with approach 1 the linking of the external lib is correct like `../../../ext_lib/libext.a` and includes like `-isystem ../../../ext_lib/include`

For approach 2 it does not link correctly - in the `.cmake` files it just says `-lexternal_lib` and the include is missing

Comment: Description "But that does not work." is not very useful. What exactly you observe which contradicts your expectations? If you got an error message, then add this message into the question post.

Comment: `fatal error: ext_lib.h: No such file or directory #include "ext_lib.h` Nowhere you set `target_include_directories(...)`. `the linking of the` Missing include file is related to compilation, not with linking.